# Complex numbers as vectors

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to know the separate circumstances under which complex numbers can or cannot be treated as vectors as relates to the following specific item.  Most importantly, rather than telling me that the language I'm using is wrong, please understand that I am seeking better language by which to describe the issue in question.  The main point of this post is for me to discover better language by which to make the following distinction so please understand that I do not already know the words I am looking for.

For a complex number $z=a+ib$ we have

$$z^2=(a+ib)(a+ib).$$

However, for a complex vector we have

$$  \vec z^2= (a+ib)(a-ib).  $$

I have found material online saying that every complex number is a vector, and that it is not always a vector.  Please help me understand the distinction between the two modes of multiplication: scalar multiplication and vector multiplication.  What language is used to make the distinction between the two cases?  How do I know if $z^2$ is supposed to have the complex conjugate in it?  I suppose I should probably say something about the norm of the vector, but I am not sure what the words are.  Please provide the formalism which makes the distinction clear.  THANKS.

Comment: Please provide pointers to the online material that is confusing you.

Comment: It was only that I found some things that said every complex number is a vector and other things that said not every complex number is.  It wasn't confusing to me, it was just that I found different page saying different things in the few pages of google results I went through.

Comment: So provide the pointers and then we can usefully comment. Your capacity for being unconfused when you read conflicting statements amazes me. If you want help resolving the conflicts, then you need to point us at those statements. If you aren't confused and you don't need help resolving the conflicts, then what is the point of your question?

Comment: You are the one who is confused.  I understood it perfectly that I read different things saying that you both can and cannot always treat complex numbers as vectors.  I think if you read my comment, it will clear up your confusion.  For the pointers, I think if you google, "Is a complex number a vector," then you will see the same google results I saw.  You wrote, "If you want help resolving conflicts...," but I don't want that! Thanks!

Comment: No. I am not in the least confused. You certainly are confused about proper behaviour on MSE.

Comment: If you're not confused are you just wrong then?  Please help me understand how I can help find the resolution you are seeking as I am not sure why you keep adding comments to my thread.  I was saying that you must be confused because you thought I was confused, and I most certainly was not: It was my absolute certainty that I saw two different and contradictory statements on the internet which prompted me to make this post. What can I help you with?  Is it all cleared up?  If so, no need to respond.  They say long convos belong in the forum, not the comments.

Comment: It is not at all surprising that you can find contradictory statements on the internet.  @RobArthan, quite reasonably, wanted to know precisely which contradictory statements you are referring to.  This would be very useful information to anyone trying to help you with your question.

Answer (score 1):

No, $(a+bi)(a-bi)$ is not $\vec{z}^2$, it is $\|\vec{z}\|^2$.  There is no such thing as the square of a vector.  $\|\vec{z}\|$ is the (Euclidean) length of the vector $\vec{z}$, which is $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, and this happens to be the same
as $\sqrt{(a+bi)(a-bi)} = \sqrt{z \overline{z}}$.

Comment: The square of a vector is commonly understood to be the dot product of the vector with itself.

Comment: Yes, certainly the square of a vector exists but even though Robert doesn't know exactly what he's talking about, I did find his comment somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Complex numbers are vectors. They form what's known as a *vector space* over $\Bbb{R}$, a term that I'm not going to explain, but is a formal, rigorous, mathematical notion of a set of objects that can be sensibly considered "vectors". Indeed, it's not hard to see how they can be identified with vectors in $\Bbb{R}^2$: you can swap between Cartesian form $a + ib \in \Bbb{C}$ and the vector $(a, b) \in \Bbb{R}^2$.

Note that this preserves the vector operations of addition and scalar multiplication (in this case, multiplying by a real number), in the sense that
$$(a + ib) + (c + id) \mapsto (a, b) + (c, d)$$
and if $r \in \Bbb{R}$,
$$r(a + ib) \mapsto r(a, b).$$
Essentially what I'm saying is, complex numbers, considered as vectors, behave identically to $\Bbb{R}^2$, and anything you can do in $\Bbb{R}^2$, there will be a parallel version in $\Bbb{C}$.

But, complex numbers are more than simply vectors in $\Bbb{R}^2$. We can multiply these complex numbers together, unlike vectors in $\Bbb{R}^2$. We can do calculus with complex numbers (differentiation and integration), unlike $\Bbb{R}^2$ (actually, we can differentiate in $\Bbb{R}^2$, but it is a different notion to differentiation with complex numbers).

So, in short, complex numbers are more than just vectors. If it helps in a problem to think of them as vectors, then please do so. However, you'll soon find that not every complex numbers problem can be solved in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Various authors may well use a different notation than I'm outlining below. I have written what is commonly used, what makes for a consistent article, and what is aligned with *wikipedia*.

For convenience in the following let $r\in\mathbb R,\,c=a+ib\in\mathbb C,\, (u,v)\in\mathbb R^2,\,(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2,\,\mathbf w=(u+iv)\in\mathbb C^1,\,\mathbf z=(x+iy)\in\mathbb C^1,$ and let $\mathbf z^*=(x-iy)$ represent the *conjugate transpose*.

### Vector spaces and their scalar product

We are talking about the following *vector spaces* over *fields* with *vector addition* and *scalar multiplication*. They are defined using the usual addition and multiplication of the corresponding fields.

1. $(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R,+,\cdot)$ with scalar product $r\cdot(x,y)=(rx,ry)$.
2. $(\mathbb C^1,\mathbb R,+,\cdot)$ with scalar product $r\cdot \mathbf z = r\cdot(x+iy) =rx+iry$.
3. $(\mathbb C^1,\mathbb C,+,\cdot)$ with scalar product $c\cdot \mathbf z = (a+ib)\cdot(x+iy) = (ax-by)+i(ay+bx)$.

The notation $\mathbb C^1$ is used here to emphasize that it is a set of *vectors*.
The notation $\mathbf z$ is used here for a vector, although we can also write $z$ if there is no ambiguity.
Vector spaces 1 and 2 are *isomorphic*. They are commonly treated as if they are simply the same.
Note that the multiplication dot is commonly left out for convenience (e.g. $r\mathbf z$).

### Dot product of vectors

The *dot product* is the sum of the products of the corresponding entries of two sequences of numbers.
Various authors may well use a different convention, and for instance treat the dot product as an inner product or vice versa.
But strictly speaking, for the vectors in each of the cases, it should be:

1. The dot product $(u,v)\cdot(x,y)=ux+vy$.
2. The dot product $\mathbf w \cdot \mathbf z = (u+iv)\cdot(x+iy)=(ux-vy) + i(uy+vx)$.
3. The dot product $\mathbf w \cdot \mathbf z = (u+iv)\cdot(x+iy)=(ux-vy) + i(uy+vx)$.

It is actually ambiguous that we use a dot for regular multiplication, for the scalar product, and for the dot product. But given the context in which they are used, there is usually no confusion.

### Inner products

The usual *inner product* in each case is:

1. $\langle (u,v),\,(x,y)\rangle = ux+vy \in\mathbb R$.
2. $\langle \mathbf w,\mathbf z \rangle=ux+vy \in\mathbb R$.
3. $\langle \mathbf w,\mathbf z \rangle=\mathbf z^*\mathbf w = (u+iv)(x-iy) = (ux+vy)+i(vx-uy) \in\mathbb C$.

In case 1 the dot product and the inner product are the same, and they are used interchangeably. We can't do that in cases 2 and 3 though.
It is rare to see the inner product of case 2. Usually case 3 is implied.

Just for fun, in *Quantum Physics* the notation $\langle \phi|\psi\rangle = |\phi\rangle^\dagger|\psi\rangle$ is used for the inner product of two quantum states or probability densities.

### Vector norms

The usual *vector norm* in each case is:

1. $\|(x,y)\| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \in\mathbb R$.
2. $\|\mathbf z\| = \sqrt{\langle \mathbf z,\mathbf z\rangle} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\in\mathbb R$.
3. $\|\mathbf z\| = \sqrt{\langle \mathbf z,\mathbf z\rangle} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\in\mathbb R$.

No confusion here. They are all exactly as we would expect.